# Leave directory out using ls

Tags: debian, ls

I am trying to get a vertical list from `ls`, that is recursive but leaves a out a single directory called `node_modules`.

I've used:

```
ls -lt -h -R
```

This gets me a very long list that is vertical, human readable and recursive. But it has the directory `node_modules` included and that just has too many files and directories.

Comment: Add `-I node_modules`

Comment: `find . -name node_modules -prune -o -print`.

Comment: Mangle the output from `ls` with `grep` or some of the other filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `-I` to ignore the directory as Stephane [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126754/leave-directory-out-using-ls#comment202656_126754) or, better, avoid using `ls` altogether. Just use `find` which is far better for this kind of thing and can deal with strange file names gracefully:

```
find . | grep -v node_modules
```

Or, for a safer approach that can deal with newlines in file names correctly:

```
find . -not -regex ".*node_modules.*"
```

or, for non-GNU `find`:

```
find . ! -regex ".*node_modules.*"
```

If you can have `node_modules` as part of a file name and don't want to skip that one, use this instead:

```
find . -not -regex "./node_modules.*"
```

Comment: `\! -name 'node_modules'` would be okay (instead of the regex) as it seems that's the full name of the thing to leave out.

Comment: That is excellent, thank you very much. I need it to display in a word document, I would like it nice and neat because its going in a uni report.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf no it's not, that will remove the directory but return the list of the files contained in that directory which is exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread the OP. Then you can use `-prune` to entirely cut the branch: `find . -name 'node_modules' -prune -o -true` (but this also outputs the dir name—but doesn't recurse into) or `find . ! -name 'node_modules' -o -name 'node_modules' -prune -false` to not recurse into and not show it.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes, I know about `-prune` :) How is that better than my approach though? It seems absurdly complex for such a simple operation.

Comment: I have no idea about efficiency, a benchmark would be good. I vaguely keep memories that regexes are evil and slow (and ugly `:D`), but I have no concrete facts to backup this statement! Moreover, I have absolutely no idea if `find` is smart enough to prune early with the regex (maybe).

Comment: Actually, talking about absurdly complex commands, here's what my prune approach boils down to, after reduction (I don't know why I thought of the previous ugly one): `find . ! \( -name 'node_modules' -prune \)`. Do you like it better now? `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf ah yes, that one is indeed better.

Comment: Thinking about it, I find it beautiful! It's like `! -name 'node_modules' -o -false` but with the special pruning action. Very cute.